# Why include a Repo.SaveChanges() method in a repository?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I'm in a discussion with another developer about whether or not to have a `repo.SaveChanges()` method exposed in our Entity Framework 5 repository.

We're considering having a repo that automatically saves changes like this (quick and dirty example):

```
public class Repo {
    private OurEfContext _context = new OurEfContext();

    public void PersistCustomer(Customer cust)
    {
        // update customer code here
        _context.SaveChanges(); //  <-- is this okay?
    }
}
```

The other option we're considering is to expose a separate Repo.PersistChanges() method like this:

```
public class Repo {
    private OurEfContext _context = new OurEfContext();

    public void PersistCustomer(Customer cust)
    {
        // update customer code here
        // no call to _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void PersistChanges()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Most examples that I have seen use the second pattern. Is one pattern more 'correct' than the other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Saving after every change prevents you from saving batches of entities. In certain graph structures this can be a correctness problem, in other cases it just drives the CPU load up. The cost of `SaveChanges` is not just the writing, but also traversing entities loaded into the context.

Why work *against* Entity Framework? Do, what it wants you to do: Save batches and call `SaveChanges` at the end when all changes to entities have been made.

The method `PersistCustomer` is wrongly named: It persists everything, not just the customer. You cannot persist a single entity with EF. Your abstraction (the repository) is broken.

People often wrap EF in a generic repository that adds no functionality but removes functionality. That has never made sense to me.

Comment: I am confused as to which method your advocating.

Comment: Call `SaveChanges` at the end when all changes to entities have been made.

Comment: The abstraction is not broken and I don't see the generic repository. You probabbly assume that the Customer is an EF entity, it might be so but it might be an actual business object. The repository just maps the Customer to EF entities (maybe there are more than one). It's the correct usage, because the repository should hide EF in the first place anyway

Answer (score 3):

I tend to support the second method.

The first one might "hide" the saving action and will look nicer to the user,
but don't forget that you are losing control of the saving action.
If you find yourself updating multiple entities, this will cause an overhead of multiple separated changes instead of having them executing at once - which means more execution time.

Eventhough it might feel like calling the "SaveChanges" redundantly, the second method will allow you to save multiple changes at once **= no overhead.**

I find limiting yourself by removing the ability to improve the performance as a needless act.

Comment: It's called Separation of Concerns and the repository in this scenario should be part of an unit of work, coordinated by a higher level than persistence

Answer (score 2):

I moved to the first method for two reasons:

1) Sometimes (not often) I forgot to call `SaveChanges()` method. For example when I had to commit also a transaction (or I saved the changes but forgot to commit a transaction) and my not ideal tests did not catch this kind of error (It is similar to approach that you don't call `Validate()` function every time you change something in your business entity, because you can forgot to call it (even that this is not the only reason)).

2) Repository interface can be turned into in memory repository (for testing purpose) and there is no sense to call `SaveChanges()`, it can be confusing, because standard collection doesn't have this kind of method and implementation should be hidden for the user.

If I need to add an collection, I can add another method to the repository `Import(List<Customer> customers)` execute `foreach` and call `SaveChanges()` after that. This is also clear for the user, that some optimized method exists.

If I need perform multiple operations on multiple repositories, I can wrap all operations by a transaction (every little change can be locked in relational database to avoid inconsistency or deadlock, until transaction is not commited as a whole).

But I don't see the first or second method better, both have trade offs and probably it is a matter of personal preference ?